# What is difference between "Hive on Spark" with "Spark SQL with Hive Metastore"? In production, Which one should be used? Why?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

This is my opinion:

> Hive on Spark provides Hive with the ability to utilize Apache Spark as its execution engine.Spark SQL also supports reading and writing data stored in Apache Hive.Hive on Spark only uses Spark execution engine. Spark SQL with Hive Metastore not only uses Spark execution engine, but also uses Spark SQL Which is a Spark module for structured data processing and to execute SQL queries. Due to Spark SQL with Hive Metastore does not support all of Hive configurations and all version of the Hive metastore(Available versions are 0.12.0 through 1.2.1.), In production, The deploy mode of Hive on Spark is better and more effective.

So, am I wrong? Does anyone have others ideas?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42910178/spark-sql-how-does-it-tell-hive-to-run-query-on-spark/42916572#42916572

Comment: I think following link would clear your doubts. :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611744/sparksql-vs-hive-on-spark-difference-and-pros-and-cons