# Is there a difference in SQL queries used in SparkSQL and in HiveQL?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Are they interchangeable? Or is one a subset of the other? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SparkSQL vs Hive on Spark - Difference and pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611744/sparksql-vs-hive-on-spark-difference-and-pros-and-cons)

Answer (score 0):

So it may depend what programs you are using, but I have found a source:

> Hive on Spark is similar to SparkSQL, it is a pure SQL interface that use spark as execution engine, SparkSQL uses Hive's syntax, so as a language, I would say they are almost the same.

So to answer your question, the syntax should mostly be interchangeable but they seem to be used for different purposes.

[See this post here for more information about Hive and Spark.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37483417/1712345)